# How do I get the Emacs Lisp Intro manual in my info system?

Tags: doom, documentation, info, manual

I recently switched to Doom Emacs and went to find the "Emacs Lisp Intro Manual", and it's not in there. Is there a way to add it? Or, am I just looking in the wrong place?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What Elisp *tutorial*? Do you mean the Elisp *manual*? Info is for manuals, not tutorials. Your question isn't very clear, so far.

Comment: [This document](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html) references a manual. I should be able to do something like `C-h i m Emacs Lisp Intro` to find it, but it's not there. The document I referenced feels more like a tutorial than a manual.

Comment: It's called a manual. If it doesn't show up in your Info list of manuals then please edit your question so say that that's the problem. Normally that manual's included with an Emacs build.

Comment: Be sure you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) when debugging this. If you don't see the problem when doing that then bisect your init file to find the culprit. Update your question itself with the recipe to repro the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`. Thx.

Comment: okay, I have edited my question. let me know if this makes more sense

Comment: `C-h i m Emacs Lisp Intro` should work if the manual is installed on your system, so that suggests that the manual is not installed. How did you install Emacs and what OS/distro are you using?

Comment: What @NickD (and I) said. If you see the problem when you start Emacs without an init file then it sounds like your Emacs installation doesn't include that manual. Show some more info about your installation and how you're starting Emacs.

Comment: This is the first time I have ever used a configuration framework for emacs, so i am doing lots of digging. Running Doom Emacs on MacOS. I'll try starting up without  the init files next. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using my psychic debugging hat I will guess that you are using Ubuntu or another Linux distribution based on Debian. Debian is infamous for declaring that the Emacs manuals are not Free and therefore cannot be installed by default. To install them, enable the `non-free` repository and install the `emacs-common-non-dfsg` package.

Opinions differ about whether the documentation is Free or not, but I think that Debian’s reasoning is pretty dumb. Or at least overly legalistic.

Comment: ah.. yes, this is Doom Emacs running on MacOS..